# How to change Xamarin Forms UI depending on claims read from JWT token given by an Web API

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.essentials

This question's scenario is looks like this：

My android app (xamarin forms) has been authenticated by a Web API. The API gives a JWT token to app, then app deserialize and store it also read and saved claims which token carried by Xamarin Essentials.

So, How to use saved token claims value from Xamarin Essentials to control a xaml page UI show or hide?

for example:

```
normal UI                  XE stores certain claim value's UI

<UI component A>           <UI component A>
<UI component B>           <UI component B>
<UI component C>           <UI component C>
<UI component D>           <UI component D>
                           <UI component X>
```

Comment: set a bool in your VM that shows/hides the extra menu option.  Or add the option dynamically based on the JWT.  There are dozens of ways to approach this.  It's difficult to give specific advice on such a broad question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.